# Ajax method not getting called using SpringMVC portlet in Liferay 6.1

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, liferay

I using SpringMVC portlets with Liferay 6.1. I am trying to make an ajax call from tha jsp but the method is not getting called and I get an error as below

failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 404 (not found)

My jsp ajax method is

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url:'<portlet:resourceURL id="ajax" ></portlet:resourceURL>',
                data: {id:data},
                type: 'POST',
                datatype:'json',
                success: function(respData) {

                    alert(respData);
                    jQuery('#farmerProfile').html(respData);
                }
            });
```

and my servResource method signature in the controller class is

```
@ResourceMapping(value="ajax")
public void serveResource(
        PortletConfig config, ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response)


        throws Exception {
```

My controller class is implementing the

```
   org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.Controller interface
```

Can anybody shed some light on it?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

ajax POST gets handled by Portlet processAction.
ajax GET gets handled by serverRequest.

So, change your 'type' to from 'POST' to 'GET'

Answer (score 1):

This [sample portlet](http://code.google.com/p/portletsinaction/downloads/detail?name=ch12_SpringPortletDateTime.zip&can=2&q=) from "Portlets-in-action" book can be used as a reference to debug your code.

Hope this helps.